# Mutt send email with attachment to personal and corporate email address

Tags: sendmail, attachment, mutt

[Mutt | CentOS 5.1] I have set up Mutt on CentOS and configured /etc/Muttrc and ~/.muttrc files.
I can send email out without attachments, command:

```
echo $Message | mutt -s "WARNING $Subject" sample@gmail.com
```

and this works well for corporate's email address, e.g.

```
echo $Message | mutt -s "WARNING $Subject" sample@corp.domain
```

When sending email with attachments, weird results come out. I will explain in cases as below.

1> When send to personal email address (*sample@gmail.com*), multiple files can be attached.

```
echo $Message | mutt -s "NORMAL $Subject" sample@gmail.com \
     -a test1.log -a test2.log
```

2> When send to corporate email address (*sample@corp.domain*), emails cannot be sent out if files attached. (cmd similar as above). But the interesting thing is, if I attach the */root/install.log* FIRST, the email can be sent out with attachments, cmd as below:

```
echo $Message | mutt -s "NORMAL $Subject" sample@corp.domain \
      -a /root/install.log -a test1.log -a test2.log
```

Case would fail to send if attachment order changed.

I cannot figure out where the problem exists from above cases, any configuration I may miss?

Answer (score 3):

Since you are piping stuff into mutt, you must use the `-x` (mailx compose mode) option first.

Comment: Can you provide a full command for reference? BTW, this doesn't explain why case 1 succeeds to send email, while case 2 not.

Comment: `echo $Message | mutt -x -s "WARNING $Subject" sample@gmail.com` You do that because mutt is a console (curses) application and you're piping something to its stdin, so it has to read from stdin.

Answer (score 0):

From mutt(1):

```
   -a file [...]
          Attach  a  file  to  your  message  using MIME.  When attaching single or  multiple files, separating filenames and
          recipient addresses with "--" is mandatory, e.g. mutt -a image.jpg -- addr1 or mutt  -a  img.jpg  *.png  --  addr1
          addr2.  The -a option must be placed at the end of command line options.
```

Comment: Do you mind provide more details and explain the different results between case 1 and 2?

Comment: The man page says that you should specify -a only once. Anyway, I just tried commands like: echo test | mutt -s "prova" emanuele@example.com -a /tmp/wut.png -a /etc/motd. They work, also with gmail accounts.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same problem today.  You don't say what the error msg is, but I bet it said "can't stat  unable to attach file".

This is the solution.
"--" is mandatory, e.g. mutt -a image.jpg --  Note: The -a option must be placed at the end of command line options.

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1586810
http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/mutt-someone@somedomain-com-unable-to-attach-file-844315/

bugs.launchpad.net /ubuntu/+source/mutt/+bug/805613